# How to get Refresh Token from Spring Authorization Server sample

Tags: spring, spring-security, authorization, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

The official sample Spring Authorization Server returns an **access_token** and **id_token** by default for Oauth 2.1 with PKCE

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/default-authorizationserver

Is it possible that the endpoint **/oauth2/token** also returns a **refresh_token** in the response? What changes or configuration would I need in the sample for getting a **refresh_token**?

Here's a Postman request for the token
[image]

I will also mention a few changes I had to make for Code Flow with PKCE

Disabled CSRF

```
http
    .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
        authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
    .formLogin(withDefaults())
    .csrf().disable();
```

Changed ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC to ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE

Changed requireAuthorizationConsent(true) to requireProofKey(true)

Comment: Actually it does return a refresh token as well. Just checked on the recent changes of the sample you mentioned

Comment: Can you provide additional details for how you're using the token endpoint and what your configuration is? As @AndreyGrigoriev said, the default sample (unchanged) does return a refresh token in the case of `authorization_code`.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I just included a snapshot for the Postman request for a token.

Comment: Thanks @abbas. Your question doesn't mention using a public client. The postman request doesn't appear to have credentials (though it may in the Headers section and I cannot see it). I'd recommend putting all of the information about your use case in the question as text and not a screenshot. Having said that, I believe I have answered the question with the assumption that you're using a public client. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You mention using the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE, which is valid for confidential clients as well as public clients. However, when using a public client (client authentication method = none, no client secret), refresh tokens are not issued.

From [#297](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297) Implementation guidelines for Browser-Based Apps (SPA):

> **Refresh Tokens for Public Clients**
>
> There are no plans to implement refresh tokens for Public Clients, as there are no browser APIs that allow refresh tokens to be stored in a secure way, which would result in an increased attack surface.

See #297 for more information about refresh tokens, which is heavily based on recommendations from [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-08) and [OAuth 2.0 Security Best Current Practice](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-19). The recommendation when using a public client is to use the ["backend for frontend"](https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/) pattern. The BFF will be a confidential client and can receive refresh tokens while also removing the complexity and risk of managing and storing tokens in the browser.

Comment: Refresh tokens for public clients have been implemented now after all: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/pull/1432